# How to avoid an endless construct loop?

Tags: php, class, construct

I have two classes that depend on each other.

```
class ClassA extends SomeClass
{
    public function __construct(ClassB $classB) {
        $this->classB = $classB;
    }
}

class ClassB extends SomeOtherClass
{
    public function __construct(ClassA $classA) {
        $this->classA = $classA;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid an endless loop as they're constructed?

Comment: By not having them depend on each other...

Comment: ClassA does not create a new ClassB in the __construct method, the $classB object is passed to the constructor already created - do you actually get a loop?

Comment: I thought this was causing an error, but I guess it was due to something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any loop. Neither of them instantiate a new object in their constructors.